# 複数のシーンを一つにまとめる方法

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

C#経験ありのUnity初心者です。
Unityで複数scene(シーン)を一つにまとめる方法

以下を実施したいと思っていますが、ググっても情報が出てこず、困っています。
・シーンA：機能A（ボタン押下で処理を実施）、ネームスペースは「Test.A」。
・シーンB：機能B（ボタン押下で機能Aとは異なる処理を実施）、ネームスペースは「Hoge.B」。
・機能Aと機能Bを持つシーンCを新たに作成したい。
※シーンCを新たに作成して機能AとBを持たせるか、シーンAに機能Bを追加するような形でも構いません。

サンプルコードをネットから落としてきているため、機能Aと機能Bのネームスペースが異なる点もネックです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 機能を修正したいため、ビルドによる結合ではなく、シーン上でまとめたいと思っています。

Comment: マルチシーンを使用するのはどうでしょうか。AとBを使用するCを実装するイメージです。